# Use csh variable in script

Tags: csh

I am writing a csh script and I have set these variables from the prompt:

```
set sYYYY = `expr $startdate : '\(....\)'`
set sMM   = `expr $startdate : '....\(..\)'`
```

And now I want to use them and save them in another file like:

```
 echo " files_path  = '/path_file/$sYYYY_$sMM/'" >> user_file.txt
```

I having trouble getting these variables to print properly to the user_file file.

Anybody has an idea how do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you source the script, it can see the current shell's variables. If you don't want to *have* to source it, then make them environment variables instead.